# How can I wrap a method with a callback parameter into a Task?

Tags: c#, callback, task-parallel-library, silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight 5 application with a bunch of methods having a signature similar to this:

```
public void AskConfirmation(Action<bool> callback);
```

Typically these methods raise an InteractionRequest to interact with the user, waiting for input.

I'd like to leverage the Task Parallel Library and the async/await keywords, and so I want to define a second method with the following signature :

```
public Task<bool> AskConfirmation();
```

And this second method would rely on the first one. Unfortunately I just couldn't figure out how to implement it.

Wrapping asynchronous operations into Tasks is easy when they follow the Event-based Asynchronous pattern or the Begin/End pattern, but these were clear overkills in my case so I didn't want to implement them. But now I'm stuck. Did anybody ever faced the same problem and found a solution for it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, are you looking for Continuations? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx

Comment: The goal here is indeed to be able to define continuations instead of a callback parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public Task<bool> AskConfirmation()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    AskConfirmation(b => tcs.TrySetResult(b));
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Just one thing, you should wrap the 'AskConfirmation' with try/catch and tcs.TrySetException in the catch

Comment: @Maxim actually that would be against the convention of `Task.FromAsync`, which throws itself any exception thrown by the BeginMethod, rather than returning a faulted task: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321404.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this simple answer! One thing bothers me though : shouldn't this method have no side-effects until the Start() method of its returned Task is called ? Calling this method to receive a Task object will actually "start" it immediately. Shouldn't I be able to start it later (or not start at all) ? I can certainly live with this but... :)

Comment: You're right. I missed another thing, ofcourse it depends on needs but I think it would be preferred to start the AskConfirmation in a new task, this way the method will return before the completion of the method. Then if it throws an exception you should set the Task exception.

Comment: @jpatte, Maxim: The method I gave follows the recommended pattern, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx. It's also what `Task.FromAsync` does.